# bash update huge csv file with values from another large csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I need to update selected rows of huge csv file (20M rows) with data from another big csv file (30K rows),

File to be updated is 1.csv

`1120120031,55121
1120127295,55115
6135062894,55121
6135063011,55215
4136723818,55215
6134857289,55215
4430258714,55121`

Updating file is 2.csv

`112012 ,55615
6135062,55414
6135063,55514
995707 ,55721`

Such as 1_MOD.csv

`1120120031,55621
1120127295,55615
6135062894,55421
6135063011,55515
4136723818,55215
6134857289,55215
4430258714,55121`

Modifications:

1. if $1 in 2.csv matches  substring of $1 in 1.csv (rows 1 & 2) then 
   update $2 in 1.csv as per 3rd char in $2 of matched row 2.csv;
2. Match the Maximum size of strings (rows 3 & 4);
3. Unmatched rows remain unchanged (rows 5 to 7).

So far I managed to test sed in while loop, but script will take about 31 days to complete. I believe there is a better way, such as awk file 2.csv in Array and update 1.csv with that array, something that I could not do as my Awk knowledge is limited

Thanks

Comment: When you have so big files, it will be better to use perl instead, it will be probably much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, reading in `2.csv`, and using the first field as a pattern.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = " *, *";
    OFS = ",";
}
NR==FNR {
    # Ensure there are no special characters in $1
    if ($1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/)
        a[$1] = substr($2, 3, 1);
    next;
} {
    for (n in a)
        if ($1 ~ "^"n) {
            $2 = substr($2, 1, 2) a[n] substr($2, 4, length($2) - 3);
            break;
        }
} 1
```

Comment: You can probably break the `for` loop after spotting a match, which should save some processing time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I added the `break`.

Comment: @kdhp and jonathanLeffler, many thanks guys ,in one hour you solved what I could not solve in days. I will run script for some thousands rows to see how long it will take